# How to set up gitpython on in Visual Studio Code so it is setup once

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, gitpython

I am developing on OS/X using Visual Studio Code (1.30.1). My script works but each time I close and re-open Visual Studi Code, I have to setup GitPython again. I want to set it up once and have it work.

I am developing with GitPython which I set up as follows via the VS Code Terminal window:

> python3 -m venv gitpy
>   source gitpy/bin/activate
>   pip install gitpython==2.1.11

The python file, anyfile.py, is simple (the only line that matters is as follows):

> from urllib.parse import quote

If I close and re-open the code, I cannot run the script:

> python anyfile.py

The error is as follows:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "anyfile.py", line 1, in 
    from urllib.parse import quote
ImportError: No module named parse

I can fix the issue by running the following from the Visual Studio Code Terminal window:

> source gitpy/bin/activate
>   pip install gitpython==2.1.11

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.